# gmap3 is too small while opened from mobile device

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I develop a mobile app with html5, jquery and google maps.

When I use normal map (without gmap3) the size of the street names and the overlays are big enough to see from mobile device.

But when i use gmap3 the size of the street names and overlays are really small. is there any settings that i can change from gmap3 to make it suitable for mobile too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it. In the sample that was working fine there is this line int the head tag:

< meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

With that mobile devices open the map bigger than the PC browsers so that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is still strange, could you post your 2 codes (with and without) on gmap3 forum please ?

*Notice: version 5.0 of gmap3 has been released last week*